# If I create a question with the wrong premise, should I edit to remove the wrong premise or keep it as-is?

Tags: discussion

Related question: [Why does "git pull" exec command get stuck and print nothing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27098082/why-git-pull-command-when-executed-holds-the-thread-and-prints-nothing)

I started the first example and presented the second example to complement the first one. The thing is that I made a mistake, so the second example is not actually related to the first one, then I made an update to reflect that.

But I did not removed the text from the wrong premise because I had already posted the answer and that could take away the whole context when someone reads the edit history. Nobody answered or commented yet, maybe it is reasonable to reformulate the question, but I am not sure what to do in this case.

Should I delete the text with the wrong premise or should I keep it to maintain the original question structure? What if the question had some comment or answer regarding example 2, should a different action be taken in that case?

Comment: Correct the premise. If it's not what you intended, having people answer the question based on unintended premises serves little benefit to you, and as the OP, you do have a vested interest in a correct answer too.

Comment: You know, it's kinda weird when you try to upvote a comment, and then realize it's your own comment. =.=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just bang your question in shape and make everything consistent and even reproducible! You don't need to keep the edit history for your question transparent, as long no one gave an answer, or spent efforts otherwise.

If you **really have an answer**, that you think is useful for future research on that topic, post it as an answer, instead of editing your question.

Comment: Ok I edited the question and removed the wrong premisse instead of keeping the "UPDATE:" section I created earlier explaining my own error.